# Why is there a positive temperature coefficient in a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

When the temperature in a MOSFET increases: resistance increases and mobility decreases thus avoiding thermal runaway compared to BJT.

But what is the reason for **increasing** resistance and **decreasing** mobility in MOSFET?

I thought before that it will be opposite: as temperature increases, mobility of electrons will be excited(**increase**) no matter what semiconductor we have thus resistance will also **decrease**. Why does the opposite happens in a MOSFET?

Comment: From what I recall, the automotive manufacturers found a **CHANGE** in the MOSFET temp_coeff about 30 years ago, based on how the FETS are constructed. I think there is a NASA JPL paper or POWERPOINT explaining why the change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MOSFET Temperature coefficient](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310704/mosfet-temperature-coefficient)

Comment: See also [this answer on the Spirito effect](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472375/heat-dissipation-calculation-for-mosfet/472587#472587)